# GroovyFX application run with gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle, groovyfx

i have the next sample (from groovyfx site), it's simple window.

```
import static groovyx.javafx.GroovyFX.start

start {
  stage(title: 'GroovyFX Hello World', visible: true) {
    scene(fill: BLACK, width: 700, height: 250) {
      hbox(padding: 60) {
        text(text: 'Groovy', font: '80pt sanserif') {
          fill linearGradient(endX: 0, stops: [PALEGREEN, SEAGREEN])
        }
        text(text: 'FX', font: '80pt sanserif') {
          fill linearGradient(endX: 0, stops: [CYAN, DODGERBLUE])
          effect dropShadow(color: DODGERBLUE, radius: 25, spread: 0.25)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to run it with `gradle run` ?

my `build.gradle`:

```
 apply plugin: 'groovy'

 sourceCompatibility = 1.8
 targetCompatibility = 1.8

 project.ext.set('javafxHome', System.env['JAVAFX_HOME'])

 repositories {
   mavenCentral()
 }

 configurations {
   ivy
 }

 dependencies {
   ivy "org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.3.0"
   compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.6'
   compile 'org.codehaus.groovyfx:groovyfx:0.4.0'
   compile files("${javafxHome}/rt/lib/jfxrt.jar")
 }


tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
  groovyClasspath += configurations.ivy
}
```

I might run it from IDE, but how to run it with cli and then build jar with path to Main class?

Comment: Does my answer work? If so, accept the answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in the following configuration.

Structure:

- build.gradle
- src/

  - main

    - groovy

      - Main.groovy

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
  ivy
}

dependencies {
  ivy "org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.3.0"
  compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.6'
  compile 'org.codehaus.groovyfx:groovyfx:0.4.0'
  compile files("${System.getenv('JAVA_HOME')}/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar")
}

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
  groovyClasspath += configurations.ivy
}

task run(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'Main'
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

**Main.groovy**

```
import static groovyx.javafx.GroovyFX.start

start {
  stage(title: 'GroovyFX Hello World', visible: true) {
    scene(fill: BLACK, width: 700, height: 250) {
      hbox(padding: 60) {
        text(text: 'Groovy', font: '80pt sanserif') {
          fill linearGradient(endX: 0, stops: [PALEGREEN, SEAGREEN])
        }
        text(text: 'FX', font: '80pt sanserif') {
          fill linearGradient(endX: 0, stops: [CYAN, DODGERBLUE])
          effect dropShadow(color: DODGERBLUE, radius: 25, spread: 0.25)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Have You already seen [this](http://groovyfx.org/docs/index.html) site?